# How to move baked curves in graph editior?

Tags: animation, graph-editor, audio

I just baked sound to the animation which works fine. What I want to know if there is a way for me to move the curve of the sound I just made backwards (to - frames) so it will start half way through the sound. So I basically need to move the curve or baked sound backwards so that it will start where I want it to. I've tried using some modifiers and pressing <kbd>G</kbd> etc. but none of that works.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

So I'm baking the sound to animate the speed of the rigidbodies as a test. I want to put the baked sound backwards so the speed will start changing in time of later on in the song, instead of the beginning.

Is this possible or if not, is there an alternative?

Comment: Could you show what you are doing (screen capture)? :)

Comment: @FacebFaceb Added a screenshot (if it helps)

Comment: Did you select the graph first before pressing G? You could select by pressing A (once or twice)

Comment: @FacebFaceb It doesn't work like normal animation. It has no points to move. If it helps just quickly make a new project. Apply the scale of the cube, select it in the graph editor (along the left) and then do key<bake sound to f-curves and select some music

Comment: What do you mean by 'apply the scale' of the cube, by Ctrl+A?

Comment: @FacebFaceb sorry I meant keyframe the scale

Comment: You could move the animation keyframes x frames forward, instead of to move the sound x frames backward

Comment: @FacebFaceb Thanks! It actually places the baked sound at what keyframe you're currently at so if I just go back then bake it, it starts in the right place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In 3D view, object mode select the object the sound is baked to, and in the animation tab on the left, click "Bake Action", afterwards you'll be able to move the baked f-curve around freely.

Answer (score 3):

I do a lot of sound baking, and always bake at frame 1 then use the NLA editor to change start frame, simply and quickly.  You don't want to be baking large sound files again to move a frame to the left 8^).

If you are going to use the NLA, it  also pays to create an empty action (how you want it to be with silence) and add that to the stack.

[image: NLA Example]